# Expected number of typing a string " option pricing"

Tags: probability

A monkey types letters from the alphabet plus the space bar with equal probability at the rate of one a second. how long would it take him to type the string 'option pricing'?

I guess I should be using the concept of recursion, which basically layout all the cases that will restart the typing of the string. And also I noted that if I am at the second 'o' position, I could restart at 'p' position or continue at'n' position. Can anyone give me a further hint? Should I continue the calculation or should I change an approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE and well done for showing your own thoughts.  No less than $14$ seconds.

Comment: I think the solution to this problems is related to the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263025/abracadabra-problem#:~:text=ABRACADABRA%20is%20eleven%20letters%20long,%E2%8B%852611%20keystrokes%2C%20right%3F)